# Static Number of Rows and Columns in SSRS Report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I need to create a report in SSRS that mimics an old hand written report.  There will always be 14 rows and 6 columns.  However, sometimes the query that is used for the report will not return data for a column or a row.  In that case, I want to display "--" in its place.  How would I create a report with these static rows and columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience when using SSRS, in situations like this it is best to make your data look the way you want it first. That is to say, create a set of data that has 6 columns, and for the empty rows, have some sort of placeholder or dummy data. Then, when rendering in SSRS, handle this placeholder/dummy data accordingly, in your case by displaying "--". You might need to do some sort of funky logic to build these dummy lines, aggregate logic, etc. But I've found doing the work in the data side to be easier than in SSRS.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer since my query was very complex.  After many hours of alterations, I am able to get my results.